# flutter build ios ignores --target

Tags: flutter

I am having an issue of building ios application with flutter.

I run the following command

```
flutter build ios --flavor development --debug --target=lib/main_development.dart
```

But the error shows

```
Error: Error when reading 'lib/main.dart': No such file or directory
package:my_app/main.dart: Error: No 'main' method found.
Try adding a method named 'main' to your program.
```

There is no main.dart in my application. Not sure if anyone know where in ios can override this value?

Thank you

==========================================================

**Update 1:**

My `main()` function in lib/main_development.dart looks like

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await DotEnv.load(fileName: "development.env");
  await _configureAmplify();

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CognitoServiceChangeNotifier()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => UserProfileChangeNotifier()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => BottomNavigationBarCurrentIndexChangeNotifier()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Open ios folder in `XCode`
2. Click on project and select target `Runner`
3. Navigate to `Build Setting`
4. Search and find `FLUTTER_TARGET`
5. Expand and set target file based on Schemes `${PROJECT_DIR}/../lib/main_development.dart` or `${PROJECT_DIR}/../lib/main_production.dart` or `${PROJECT_DIR}/../lib/main_stage.dart`

As your error log, the file `main.dart` is missing. By default flutter will create main.dart file while create a project and set the same in `FLUTTER_TARGET`. Make sure you reset the target in XCode project while you change the target in flutter.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. If anyone has my situation, where there was no FLUTTER_TARGET, just manually add it by clicking the plus symbol and it'll go under User-Defined.

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't saying that you don't have a main.dart file but rather don't have a `main() {}` method. Dart needs a `main() {}` method to run your program.

You don't need to change the name of the file so long as it has a method named `main` in which you run your code. It should contain the Flutter `runApp()`.

E.g.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Hi @Hady, I attached the `main()` function in the question. Please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Ben, I believe that the `main()` method needs to have a return type of `void` and not `Future<void>`. Please note that you don't need a return type of `Future` for the function to be `async`. So you can change the return type of the function to `void` and leave everything else as is and it will work fine. Hope this helps!

Comment: Did it work @Ben? I also wanted to add that you would use the Future<void> (in general use cases) if you want to make a method which awaits future and then await that method in another one. E.g. let's say you have a method that gets the username of someone. And you have a method that gets profile info. the username  method would await firestore to get the name. The profile method needs to get the username as well as the profile pic and a bunch of other info. The username method would be a Future so that you can await it in the profile method. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Hady, thank you for your follow up. Sorry I haven't tested it yet since I end up with using --dart-define to pass the environment variable for selecting the configuration file. I definitely will test it out when I get more time.

Comment: Hey @Ben no worries. Glad you figured something out!